# Find the probability of messages reaching a plane via two separate antenna towers.

Tags: probability, statistics

I am very confused on how to setup the below problem. Any advice is welcomed!

A control tower at an airport has two antennas for sending radio signals to
approaching planes. Each message is sent from the tower, (T), to antenna A, (A), and
from the tower to antenna B, (B). The probabilities for these messages to get to the
antennas are as follows:

P(TA) = 0.90 P(TB) = 0.75

These probabilities are not independent, however:

P(TB | TA) = 0.80

If the signals reach the antennas, they are sent to the plane, (P). The probabilities of
the signals getting from the antennas to the plane are as follows:

P(AP) = 0.60 P(BP) = 0.70

Note: the above two probabilities are independent of other outcomes.

Find the probability that one or more messages get to the plane.

Comment: Use what you know about conditional probabilities and the information you gave to get the probability of getting both signals. From there you can find the probability of the union of the two events.

Answer (score 0):

To get you on your way:
$$\begin{align} \mathsf P(TP) & = \mathsf P\big((TA\cap AP)\cup (TB\cap BP)\big) 
\\[1ex] & = \mathsf P(TA)~\mathsf P\big(AP\cup (TB\cap BP)\;\big\vert\; TA\big)+\mathsf P(TA^\complement)~\mathsf P\big(TB\cap BP\;\big\vert\; TA^\complement\big)
\\[1ex] & \quad \vdots\end{align}$$

Continue, using the given information on in/dependence of events, until you have an expression in known terms.